# How to assign roles in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

There are 2 roles: 1. `Admin` 2. `users` in the project.

How can I assign roles when a user is registering ?

I have 3 tables

- `users - user_id`
- `roles - role_id`
- `user_roles - userid, roleid`

Here is the code for `hasrole` - whether particular role exits.

```
public function hasRole($key) {
       //  return in_array($check, array_fetch($this->roles->toArray(), 'name'));
    foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
        if ($role->ROLE_NAME == $key) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Comment: bansi help me out here

Comment: sry, I am not good @laravel, never worked in it. this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919607/laravel-roles-permissions-with-authority